# C#: Is there a way to cast a class to an interface it implements at runtime, but not compile time?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, casting, type-safety

If I have a base class and a couple derived classes that implement an interface, e.g.:

```
public class BaseClass
{

}

public interface IInterface
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class DerivedA : BaseClass, IInterface
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // some implementation
    }
}
public class DerivedB: BaseClass, IInterface
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // some other implementation
    }
}
```

And I have an unrelated class that has a BaseClass field:

```
public class UnrelatedClass
{
    public BaseClass foo;
}
```

Provided my implementation assumes foo should be some derived class that does implement the interface (but I don't know which so I can't just cast to that class), can I somehow cast it to IInterface and call foo.SomeMethod() without generating a compile error?

P.S.- I know this is a really roundabout way to do this and should just use an "IInterface foo" field instead, but due to Unity not serializing interface fields and not wanting to write a custom inspector- this is a workaround I'm trying.

Comment: `BaseClass` doesnt have `SomeMethod`. `IInterface` has it, so why can't you put `SomeMethod` inside the `BaseClass` as e.g. `abstract`?

Comment: Why doesn't the `BaseClass` implements `IInterface`?

Comment: Use the `is` keyword to check: `if (foo is IInterface) {...}`

Comment: You probably do have a problem in your inheritance design there. What you are trying to achieve is exactly what interfaces are for. You could use reflection, but I would strongly recommend against it in this case (it would slow down your solution).

Comment: Can't you just declare UnrelatedClass.foo as an IInterface? Or make BaseClass implements IInterface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the interface method via reflection (slow!) or you can 'safe-
cast' with the `as` operator. The `as` operator 'returns' `null` if the cast fails. Like this:

```
var impl = foo as IInterface;
impl?.SomeMethod()
// or if(impl != null) impl.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Nice! Forgot about this question for a while, but this was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know you could use "as" with types that aren't convertible at compile time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a solution by changing your design. I guess your ultimate goal is that you want your `foo` object to have all the members of `BaseClass` *and* `IInterface`. You can create an abstract class like so:

```
abstract class BaseClassAndInterface: BaseClass, IInterface {
    public abstract void SomeMethod();
}
```

Now make `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` inherit from `BaseClassAndInterface` and implement the method in the interface.

```
public class DerivedA : BaseClassAndInterface
{
    public override void SomeMethod()
    {
        // some implementation
    }
}
public class DerivedB: BaseClassAndInterface
{
    public override void SomeMethod()
    {
        // some other implementation
    }
}
```

Now, `foo` can be declared as `BaseClassAndInterface`.

Comment: I thought of this- it works for the specific example I gave but falls apart if you'd like to use different base classes that implement IInterface (since you'd need an abstract base class in the middle for each of them).

I actually found a different workaround for my original problem (passing collisions between objects), but I'm still intrested in this from a hypothetical point of view: can I use interface members from an object that __does__ implement them at runtime, but the variable __doesn't__ at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

Right now your `BaseClass` has no point in your design. If you were to change your design a little bit, then you may not even need to perform checks at runtime. Here is a proposed design wherein `BaseClass` implements `IInterface` and derived classes need to override it:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public abstract class BaseClass : IInterface
{
    public abstract void SomeMethod();
    // Or virtual with common implementation
}

public class DerivedA : BaseClass
{
    public override void SomeMethod()
    {
        // some implementation
    }
}
public class DerivedB : BaseClass
{
    public override void SomeMethod()
    {
        // some other implementation
    }
}
```